# Compiler errors when parsing into x3::variant

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I´m doing more or less my first steps with X3 and already managed to parse a simple struct with 2 members. But I fail to put this struct into a variant.

The (simplified) code looks something like this:

```
struct Command1
{
            CommandType type;
            std::string objName;
}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Command1,
    type, objName
);

struct Nil {};
using Command = x3::variant<Nil, Command1>;

const x3::rule<struct create_cmd_rule, Command1> ccRule = "ccRule";
const auto ccRule_def = typeRule > identifier;

const x3::rule<struct create_rule, Command> cRule = "cRule";
const auto cRule_def = x3::omit[x3::no_case["CREATE"]] > (ccRule_def);
```

If I call it like this

```
Command1 cmd;
x3::phrase_parse(statement.cbegin(), statement.cend(), parser::cRule_def, x3::space, cmd);
```

everything is fine. But if I pass my variant:

```
Command cmd;
x3::phrase_parse(statement.cbegin(), statement.cend(), parser::cRule_def, x3::space, cmd);
```

it does not compile:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2665   'boost::spirit::x3::traits::detail::move_to': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types  ZeusCore    d:\boost_1_67_0\boost\spirit\home\x3\support\traits\move_to.hpp 224

I hope, I did not simplify the code to much...

I´m using boost 1.67 and the newest version of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Please, always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the error.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I simplified my code too much. I had BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE for most of the rules, but not for my "identifier" rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've posted it seems that the problem in referencing `*_def`. The `cRule_def` and `ccRule_def` are **not** rules, they just chained parsers stored in variables.

Try to replace:

```
const auto cRule_def = x3::omit[x3::no_case["CREATE"]] > (ccRule_def);
```

with:

```
const auto cRule_def = x3::omit[x3::no_case["CREATE"]] > (ccRule);

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(cRule, ccRule);
```

and call it like:

```
Command1 cmd;
x3::phrase_parse(statement.cbegin(), statement.cend(), parser::cRule, x3::space, cmd);
```

Here is a toy working example which I used to try to replicate the error https://wandbox.org/permlink/BMP5zzHxPZo7LUDi

Other note: `x3::omit` in `x3::omit[x3::no_case["CREATE"]]` is redundant.